# problemas con if y while

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

Este programa genera números aleatorios desde donde tu le digas, hasta donde tu le digas y cuantos tu le digas. Lo que quiero hacer es que en donde pone desde(Desde que número lo va a generar) tu le pones un número mayor que a hasta(Hasta que número genera) en vez de que no ponga nada que ponga error. Intente poner un if y un while pero no se como hacerlo.

```
 #Pantalla azul

def pantallaAzul():

 #Función

 def generador():

      dnumero1=int(dnumero.get())
      hnumero1=int(hnumero.get())
      ncantos1=int(ncantos.get())
      hnumero2=str(sample(range(dnumero1, hnumero1),ncantos1))
      resultado.set(" " + hnumero2 + "")


 #Desde

 desde = Label(app, text="Desde:  ")
 desde.configure(font="Sans 15 bold", fg='blue', bg='white')
 desde.place(x=450, y=190)

 dnumero = Entry(app, text="")
 dnumero.place(x=450, y=220)


 #Hasta

 hasta = Label(app, text="Hasta: ")
 hasta.configure(font="Sans 15 bold", fg='blue', bg='white')
 hasta.place(x=750, y=190)

 hnumero = Entry(app, text="")
 hnumero.place(x=750, y=220)


 #Cantos

 cantos = Label(app, text="Cantos: ")
 cantos.configure(font="Sans 15 bold", fg='blue', bg='white')
 cantos.place(x=450, y=290)

 ncantos = Entry(app, text="")
 ncantos.place(x=450, y=320)


 #Resultado

 resultado = StringVar()

 caixa_resultado = Label(app,textvariable=resultado, font="sans 24 bold", fg ='black', bg='white')
 caixa_resultado.place(x=550, y=500)


 #Boton

 boton = Button(app, text="Generar",command=generador)
 boton.configure(font="Sans 14 bold", fg='white', bg='blue')
 boton.place(x=625, y=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor sería validar los números desde la interfaz de usuario. Pero si quieres echarlo a andar rápidamente, puedes hacer la validación directamente en `generador`:

```
 def generador():
   dnumero1=int(dnumero.get())
   hnumero1=int(hnumero.get())
   ncantos1=int(ncantos.get())

   if hnumero1 > dnumero1:
       hnumero2=str(sample(range(dnumero1, hnumero1),ncantos1)) 
   else:
       hnumero2="Error: 'hasta' tiene que ser un número mayor a 'desde'"

   resultado.set(" " + hnumero2 + "")
```

Por cierto, esa función va a fallar si `ncantos1` es mayor que `hnumero1`-`dnumero1`.

```
>>> sample(range(1,4), 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 325, in sample
  raise ValueError("sample larger than population")
ValueError: sample larger than population
>>>
```